# How to avoid pip install package again while conda install was done before?

Tags: pip, anaconda

guys:

I use `conda install tensorflow-gpu`to install tensorflow 2.0 , and
`numpy=1.20.2` would be one of the package installed, and then I use `python3 -m pip install SOMEPACKAGE` ,this `SOMEPACKAGE` needs `numpy` to be installed as well , but `pip` seems does not check or realize the package `numpy` has already installed...

I would like to show everything I know so far :

1.I know the packages installed via `conda install` would go to  `anaconda3/envs/YOUR_ENV/lib/site-packages`

2.I use `python3 -m pip install -t anaconda3/envs/YOUR_ENV/lib/site-packages` to force the package would be installed to the place where `conda install` would be.

However,pip still tries to dwonload *.whl file and install package again,I do not want this package installation process happen again ,while it did mention that I can use `--upgrade` to replace the existed package...

So I would like to know
How does `pip` and `conda install` check if the target package has already existed before they actually to through install process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using python3 you are not using interpreter from your current conda environment so it gets installed elsewhere

python -m pip install (or simply pip install) from your activated environment should work and ignore dependencies installed by conda if they satisfy the requirements